# I accidentally uninstalled my touchpad

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, drivers, mouse, touchpad

so I was on windows 10 and my mouse suddenly stopped working, it had already happened once and it started working again after maaaany reboots.

I didn't had the patience this time so I tried something else. I uninstalled the driver thinking my touchpad would turn into an 'unknown device' and I would be able to reinstall it but instead it just disappeared ... I doesn't work anymore, not only on os like windows or ubuntu but also in the bios where it used to work before.

I tried many things (can't remember them all) but of course I did a reboot, I tried reinstalling the drivers but I had no success so far. Currently I'm on "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS", I also tried reinstalling the drivers in ubuntu, but again with no success.

I really need to make the touchpad work because I need it for school and using a mouse is not an option unfortunately.

Oh and btw my computer model is "Asus Vivobook S14".

So if you have a solution : thanks by advance for ur help !
If something isn't clear, don't hesitate I'll answer as quickly as possible with my best english lol

Comment: If it “doesn’t work in the bios” that tells me it either never worked in the bios or it did worked and that would indicate it’s a hardware failure.  So did it work in the past while you were in the bios?  You should of course [edit] your question instead of replying with a comment.  You will probably have to fallback to a USB mouse, you say this isn’t possible, but if it’s a hardware problem that’s the simplest solution you have.  This isn’t something you want to try and replace yourself

Comment: @Ramhound I guess but is it really the hardware ? Since it disappeared after I uninstalled it from windows device manager I thought there would be a solution to reinstall it back. Do you mean my touchpad is lost forever ? :'(

Comment: I asked if it ever worked in the firmware settings. Unless there is mouse navigation (most OEM hardware doesn’t have mouse navigation within the firmware settings) it probably isn’t a hardware problem but you still need a mouse at least on Windows to download the required device driver. So before you “broke” it by uninstalling the driver did it work within the firmware settings?

Comment: @Ramhound Not sure of how you would call it, it's something like [that](https://rog.asus.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=51570&d=1441678823&thumb=1) I already did that but well, I'll go back to windows to try installing the drivers again :/

Comment: Windows drivers are not used within UEFI settings, entirely different drivers are used, which tells me the reason the device stopped working before you uninstalled drivers was due to a device failure.  The fact the device isn’t detected within Linux also points to device failure

Comment: You can't "uninstall" the generic touchpad driver the comes with every OS or the BIOS/UEFI firmware driver - the driver you can uninstall is the touchpad OEM's driver that adds additional functionality _(scroll zones, double/triple tap, gestures, etc)_. If the touchpad stops working, run the BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics, as that's not a driver issue - it's either the ribbon cable connecting it to the motherboard has a loose connection, or a hardware failure of the touchpad, the ribbon cable connecting it to the motherboard, or the motherboard port it connects to.

Comment: @JW0914 Does the device manager keeps track of unplugged devices ? Because if the touch-pad is indeed disconnected by any mean, it was still showing in my windows device manager when I uninstalled it, it would explain why it didn't reappeared.

Comment: @Nizar I never said disconnected, but loose or a hardware failure resulting in an intermittent issue. Run the BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics

Comment: “Does the device manager keeps track of unplugged devices?” - No; You indicated it took several reboots typically for the device to even work which tells me, that’s a hardware issue, not a software issue (driver)

Comment: @Ramhound even if it was a software issue, touchpads are always recognized, either due to the BIOS/UEFI drivers or the generic drivers all mainstream PC OSes contain for the touchpad

Comment: @JW0914 - I would agree, I more or less indicate, the likelihood of this being a driver issue is next to zero.